# Confirm message from app to user's facebook inbox

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm implementing voting application.I want to send message from my app to users who have done voting,saying thank you with some additional message. Which api we can use implement this without user interaction(from back-end message should go to the user). dircet messages are allowed in facebook?

It is same like following function but what I need is without user interaction:

```
function facebook_send_message(to) {
FB.ui({
    app_id:'xxxxxxxx',
    method: 'send',
    name: "sdfds jj jjjsdj j j ",
    link: 'https://apps.facebook.com/xxxxxxxaxsa',
    to:to,
    description:'sdf sdf sfddsfdd s d  fsf s '

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try **Facebook App Notification API** https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications

Event though this is in beta state ,but works well. I had used this is one of my project.

```
POST /{recipient_userid}/notifications?access_token= … &template= … &href= …
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But this works only inside canvas app. In page tab how we can implement?